# Domain email after server expired

Tags: dns, cpanel

I have a site and i created an email for it like email@domainname.com
Im not intend to continue use the server but i will need the email.
The domain still have 9month to expire and i will renew that.
Will i be able to use it if the domain not point to any server?

If not,would it be a good solution to use a free server and point the domain there?

I tried it once to let the server expire and i couldnt log in then but maybe it was other error.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use your domain mails but you will have to point your MX record to one of the mail provider. If you want you can use google mail services for your domain but it's not free

OR

Try to find out cheap mail services provider.

Comment: i want to use my new hosting providers server with the same domain pointed to ther but they tolds it not possible.